# jstl iterator map and list

Tags: java, jstl

The follow code is not working:

```
    <c:forEach items="${orderNumByDepartment}" var="map2">
        <c:forEach items="${map2.value }" var="foodName2foodNum">

            <tr>
                    <td>${map2.key }</td>
                    <td>${foodName2foodNum.key }</td>
                    <td>${foodName2foodNum.value }</td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>

orderNumByDepartment is Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>> type.
```

Can you tell me why I can not get the second and third value(foodName2foodNum.key/foodName2foodNum.value)

Comment: First of all, why do you need that whitespace before the `}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foodName2foodNum is the whole map rather than a single map entry, so does not have a key and value.
If you want the String keys and the Integer values from the Map entries, try creating another c:forEach loop inside the map2.value loop. E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${foodName2foodNum}" var="thirdLoopVar">
  <p>${thirdLoopVar.key}</p>
  <p>${thirdLoopVar.value}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: map2.value is a list and foodName2foodNum is a map actually.I find the answer now I should use another forEach to iterate foodName2foodNum(map). Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Felix. I've updated the answer to match your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Map<String, List<Map<String, Integer>>>` should be `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`, because you want `foodName2foodNum` to be a map, not a list of maps and `map2` is then of type `Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.